# PHP Multiple Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following example array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [artist] => Artist43141
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [artist] => Artist2313
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [artist] => ArtistAdsa
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [artist] => ArtistAadas
        )

)
```

How do I turn it into something like: "Artist43141, Artist2313, ArtistAdsa, ArtistAadas"

I'd like to know because as far as I tried with some similar questions already answered I wasn't able to find out how.

Comment: To clarify: Rather than a nested array, you want a 1D array?

Comment: So what happened instead when you tried the other answers?

Comment: Do you want to convert the array to a space separated string only containing the array values?

Comment: @StephenTG I'm using that array source, because that's the result of a MySQL query

Comment: @MarkusHofmann yes, i want :)

Comment: @Sven Yes i did, and i tried to use array_values() as well, but wasn't very helpful

Comment: @BernardoCordeiro And your code?

Comment: Ok, I posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a space separated string containing only the values of the array.

To do so, try:

```
<?php

$array = Array
(
    array(
            'artist' => 'Artist43141'
    ),

    array(
            'artist' => 'Artist2313'
    ),

    array(
            'artist' => 'ArtistAdsa'
    ),

    array(
            'artist' => 'ArtistAadas'
    ),
);

$str = implode(' ', array_map(function($a){ return current($a); }, $array));
```

Check the PHP Manual for [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to learn more about what the above example is doing.

Happy coding!

---

### EDIT:

According to your comment:

> I have one more issue, one of my artist values has a special character 'é', and now it doesn't print them. Where should I apply the htmlspecialchars() (if that's supposed to apply)?

…I want to add the following to this answer:

**Modify the above code example like this to handle character encoding (assuming you're using UTF-8 encoding):**

```
$str = implode(' ', array_map(function($a)
{
    return htmlentities(current($a));
}, $array));
```

In case you're not using utf8 yet, start doing so by adding this to your php codes which echo to the browser:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

or the following in the header section of your html files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8" />
  ...
```

So read up on PHP's [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) and [utf8 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

Have fun.

Comment: I have one more issue, one of my artist values has a special character 'é', and now it doesn't print them. Where should I apply the htmlspecialchars() (if that's supposed to apply)?

Comment: I'll add this to my answer. Just a sec. :-)

Comment: I have done what you told me to do.
It still shows 'Ã©' instead of 'é'. I have done a dump_var of my original array and it shows the Ã©, and also I have done 'echo json_encode($array);' and the json prints the right character :(

EDIT:
I have now used the header() instead of using the html tags and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Yay! Congrats. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 5):

I would say something like this would work just fine:

```
$newArray = array_map(function($a) {return $a['artist'];},$oldArray);
```

No need for loops, or anything so complicated.

Comment: Beat me to the punch, by a couple of seconds. No need for my answer

Comment: @DarylGill I had the answer even before the question was asked... Lol I see these kind of comments quite a lot :P

Comment: Sounds like the asker wants it in the form of a string. You could just implode the array you've created though.

Comment: Hmm thx, this simplified my array :b